# What is the equivalent of the SAS IML symbol ` in R

Tags: r, sas, operators, iml

I am looking through a function as below in SAS IML

```
a = {34, 55, 67};
aT = a`;
```

what does `a'` (I could not print it here correctly but the function has the correct sign) do in SAS and what is the equivalent function in `R`?

Thanks!

Comment: `t` transpose ?

Comment: IML is not standard SAS language. You should have mentioned you use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the explanation, see [the SAS IML language regerence manual](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.3/imlug/imlug_langref_sect050.htm).

In r, you have the `t()`- function to do that. [See for instance here](https://www.marsja.se/how-to-transpose-a-dataframe-or-matrix-in-r-with-the-t-function/#:%7E:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20transpose,of%20your%20matrix%20%E2%80%9CYourMatrix%E2%80%9D.)